# Hello there , I have been trying to resolve these errors for a while and i cannot seem to find find any solutions online

Tags: flutter, dart

```
await _myRecorder.openRecorder(
        focus: AudioFocus.requestFocusAndStopOthers,
        category: SessionCategory.playAndRecord,
        mode: SessionMode.modeDefault,
        device: AudioDevice.speaker);
    await _myRecorder.setSubscriptionDuration(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
    await initializeDateFormatting();

    await Permission.microphone.request();
    await Permission.storage.request();
    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
  }
```

*errors thrown*

**The named parameter 'focus' isn't defined.

Undefined name 'AudioFocus'.

The named parameter 'category' isn't defined.

Undefined name 'SessionCategory'.

The named parameter 'mode' isn't defined.

Undefined name 'SessionMode'.

The named parameter 'device' isn't defined.

Undefined name 'AudioDevice'.**

Comment: Did you import these packages correctly?

Comment: import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show DateFormat;

Comment: yes as these are the packages i imported

Comment: Please add them to your description and not as a comment. It is hard to read.

Comment: Where are the `AudioFocus`, `SessionCategory`, `SessionMode`, and `AudioDevice` classes supposed to be defined?  I don't see them from `package:flutter_sound` nor from `package:assets_audio_player`.